# XSS security for Jquery parseHTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xss

The following code selects the text "50m / 80m", from example.com/field, then replaces it in another table on example.com.

Is this code susceptible to XSS? If so, is DOMpurify needed, or is there a simpler way to handle this?

**HTML**

```
<html>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td>50m / 80m </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**JS, JQuery**

```
 function getData(field, count) {
    if (field != "") {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: "https://www.example.com/" + field,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (result) {
          var parsed = jQuery.parseHTML(result);
          selects = jQuery(parsed).find("table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1)");
          selectv = jQuery(parsed).find("table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2)");

          var fc = selects[0].firstChild.data;
          var fcspl = fc.split(" / ");
          var ft = fcspl[0].trim();

          callback(ft, count);
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
          console.log(request);
        },
      });
    }
  }

  function callback(data, count) {
    var f = convertNum(data);
    if (f >= 30000000) {
      jQuery(
        "table#tag  tr:eq(" + count + ") td:eq(1)"
      ).replaceWith(
        '<td>' + data + "</td>"
      );
}
```

Comment: if convertNum coverts the data to a number then it's safe as it won't enter the if statement, there is no XSS  using just numbers

Comment: What does `converNum` do?

Comment: So you're concerned about `jQuery.parseHTML(result)`?

Comment: Your code doesn't really work with the given input. It's a bit hard to understand how `var fc = selects[0].firstChild.data;` could ever work, `<tr>` can't really have raw TextNode (from where to get `.data`) like that, they need an inner element, except if you're targeting a comment node. Then, as has been asked before, seeing what `convertNum` would help a bit, but anyway, the true problem in that code is neither `convertNum` nor `parseHTML`, the problem is `replaceWith(markup)`.

Comment: Even assuming you targeted the textContent of the selected `<tr>`, building that markup like that would indeed create an XSS vector: https://jsfiddle.net/74qs6j38/ So the question is, do you really need to treat `data` as markup? You anyway seem to have tried to get only the text content (from `TextNode.data`), so why not just set it back as text ([`replaceWith($("<td>", { text: data }))`](https://jsfiddle.net/74qs6j38/1/))?